# Merge two codes to pick up data

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm trying to pull customer data from my store, I have a code that does exactly what I need, except that some attributes have the value as text, so it returns me 0. Even with a text value, magento assigns a numeric value to the attribute , I know where to get that number from this attribute, how would I get this attribute number per client?

**In this code I get the numeric values ​​of the attribute with text value**

```
$config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');

$attribute = $config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'esmart_address_type');
$values    = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
print_r($values);

//here is another method
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
$values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->toOptionArray();
print_r($values);
```

**Return**

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 8993
        [label] => Residencial
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => 8994
        [label] => Comercial
    )
```

From this other way it's how I get the customer's data, I make a repeat loop to pick up from all the customers, however as I explained the attributes with text values ​​come as 0, I would need to bring the number value as in the code above, as would I implement the above code in this current to bring all the data together?

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(0);


$users = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();

$i = 1;
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    $id = $user->getId();

    $usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id);

    $tudo = array('id'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getId()), 'endereço_id'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getId()), 'smsmessagex'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getEsmartFlSmsMessage()), 'smsmessagexx'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getEsmartFlSmsConfirmation()), 'prefixo'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getPrefix()), 'nome'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getFirstname()), 'relaçao'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getEsmartRelationship()), 'ocasiao'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getEsmartOccasion()), 'tipoend'=>addslashes($usuario_loaded->getEsmartAddressType()));

    var_dump($tudo);
}
```

I can bring all fields with `'example'=>addslashes($user_loaded-> getExample())` but fields that have been created with text value bring me`0` or `''`

What I Pull

```
'tipoend'=>addslashes($username_loaded->getEsmartAddressType())

array (1) {
  ["tipoend"] =>
  string (1) "0"
}
```

What I'd like to pull 
Only with getEsmartAddressType I do not get this value I need, how would I get the value 8993 as I get in the first code? I need to get each customer (70 thousand).

```
'tipoend'=>addslashes($username_loaded->getEsmartAddressType())

array (1) {
  ["tipoend"] =>
  string (1) "8993"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontendLabel();
```

or

```
$model->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```

**your example**

```
'tipoend'=>addslashes($username_loaded->getAttributeText('esmart_address_type'))
```

**UPDATE**

also this line is wrong (you can't load addresses with user id)

```
$usuario_loaded = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id);
```

because address entities have their own ids

Comment: I got the name of the label, I need the values ​​inside it.

Comment: you mean you need both option id and value? i use both getAttributeText and getData().

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to get this data from the customer id because I need to know what information they have marked so I can add it to the new bank, but I am afraid that it is not possible to recover this data in this way

Comment: as far i can judge you are loading a customer/address collection by customer id. which is wrong. normally you will have to filter by customer id. or get all addresses with $customer->getAddresses() getter from loaded customer model.